# Last Character of regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use a regex to detect a pattern in the current page query string.

For this reason I have the following regex:

```
var re = new RegExp("([?|&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)", "i");
```

I am testing it against this input:

```
http://127.0.0.1:33822/?year=2015&country=Portugal&format=psd
```

And it works just fine finding the pattern.

What I am really trying to get is the last character index relative to the whole URL.

So for example if I want the index o the last 'd' character:

```
http://127.0.0.1:33822/?year=2015&country=Portugal&format=ps**d**
```

In this specific case I would want 60.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're linking to your localhost... we won't be able to access `127.0.0.1` because that points to our machines, not your machine. You'll need to provide a different URL if you'd like for us to view your references. There are ways to expose your `locahost` by using something like `ngrok`. There are other methods available as well.

Comment: @wcarroll I think the URL's only are examples ;)

Comment: oh I see. Good catch!

Comment: The Url's dont matter just the querrystrings themselfves

Comment: Something's unclear here. The way you ask, a simple `length` on the string would do it. Are you trying to find the index of the end of a specific query parameter (which your regex hints - `key`)?

Comment: I really did not remembered the length property, but thanks for the help

Comment: What's wrong with simply doing `length - 1` if you want the index of the last character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match.index` for that. It will give you where the match exists in the original string.
Then you can use the `matche[0].length` to find the last character in the match

```
 key='format'
 re = new RegExp("([?|&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)", "i");
 url='http://127.0.0.1:33822/?year=2015&country=Portugal&format=psd'

match=url.match(re)

console.log(match.index + match[0].length-1) // 60
```